# Class or Metaclass Design for Astrodynamics Engine

Tags: python, math, oop, simulation, physics

Gurus out there:

The differential equations for modeling spacecraft motion can be described in terms of a collection of acceleration terms:

```
d2r/dt2 =  a0 + a1 + a2 + ... + an
```

Normally a0 is the point mass acceleration due to a body (a0 = -mu * r/r^3); the "higher order" terms can be due to other planets, solar radiation pressure, thrust, etc.

I'm implementing a collection of algorithms meant to work on this sort of system. I will start with Python for design and prototyping, then I will move on to C++ or Fortran 95.

I want to design a class (or metaclass) which will allow me to specify the different acceleration terms for a given instance, something along the lines of:

```
# please notice this is meant as "pseudo-code"
def some_acceleration(t):
    return (1*t, 2*t, 3*t)

def some_other_acceleration(t):
    return (4*t, 5*t, 6*t)

S = Spacecraft()
S.Acceleration += someacceleration + some_other_acceleration
```

In this case, the instance S would default to, say, two acceleration terms and I would add a the other two terms I want: `some acceleration` and `some_other_acceleration`; they return a vector (here represented as a triplet). Notice that in my "implementation" I've overloaded the `+` operator.

This way the algorithms will be designed for an abstract "spacecraft" and all the actual force fields will be provided on a case-by-case basis, allowing me to work with simplified models, compare modeling methodologies, etc.

How would you implement a class or metaclass for handling this?

I apologize for the rather verbose and not clearly explained question, but it is a bit fuzzy in my brain.

Thanks.

Comment: Not to knock Python, but there are environments specifically tailored to computation-heavy tasks like this. Matlab comes to mind. It's possible that some of what you want to do will come more naturally or easily there.

Comment: @Carl: Python is for prototyping the solution before I move on to a more powerful, compiled language. If the logic and design work well in Python, I have done 80% of the work required to deploy an awesome application in C++. As for tailoring the solution for computation-heavy tasks, well, that's my job :)

Comment: Depending on the tasks, a few benchmarks I performed show comparable performance in MATLAB & Python and both languages have similar capabilities (when you include numpy/scipy/matplotlib with Python).  The only reason I would recommend someone switch from one to the other is MATLAB toolboxes specific to your field (to MATLAB) or price (to Python) - otherwise, I think prototyping in MATLAB/Python is perfect before optimizing...  By the way, I assume that you found a solution since this is quite old?

Comment: Yes. I settled for a design that worked well. I was not so interested in speed (that is secondary - design comes first), because eventually everything will be implemented in C++, but the prototype needs to be done rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

[PyDSTool](http://pydstool.sourceforge.net) lets you build up "components" that have spatial or physical meaning, and have mathematical expressions associated with them, into bigger components that know how to sum things up etc. The result is a way to specify differential equations in a modular fashion using symbolic tools, and then PyDSTool will create C code automatically to simulate the system using fast integrators. There's no need to see python only as a slow prototyping step before doing the "heavy lifting" in C and Fortran. PyDSTool already moves everything, including the resulting vector field you defined, down to the C level once you've fully specified the problem.

Your example for second order DEs is very similar to the "current balance" first-order equation for the potential difference across a biological cell membrane that contains multiple types of ion channel. By Kirchoff's current law, the rate of change of the p.d. is

dV/dt = 1/memb_capacitance * (sum of currents)

The example in [PyDSTool/tests/ModelSpec_tutorial_HH.py](http://pydstool.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzr/pydstool/annotate/head%3A/tests/ModelSpec_tutorial_HH.py) is one of several bundled in the package that builds a model for a membrane from modular specification components (the [ModelSpec](http://www2.gsu.edu/~matrhc/ModelSpec.html) class from which you inherit to create your own - such as "point_mass" in a physics environment), and uses a macro-like specification to define the final DE as the sum of whatever currents are present in the "ion channel" components added to the "membrane" component. The summing is defined in the [makeSoma](http://pydstool.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzr/pydstool/annotate/head:/Toolbox/neuralcomp.py#L719) function, simply using a statement such as 'for(channel,current,+)/C', which you can just use directly in your code.

Hope this helps. If it does, feel free to ask me (the author of PyDSTool) through the help forum on sourceforge if you need more help getting it started.

Answer (score 1):

For those who would like to avoid numpy and do this in pure python, this may give you a few good ideas.  I'm sure there are disadvantages and flaws to this little skit also.  The "operator" module speeds up your math calculations as they are done with c functions:

```
from operator import sub, add, iadd, mul
import copy

class Acceleration(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y, z):
      super(Acceleration, self).__init__()
      self.accel = [x, y , z]
      self.dimensions = len(self.accel)

   @property
   def x(self):
      return self.accel[0]

   @x.setter
   def x(self, val):
      self.accel[0] = val


   @property
   def y(self):
      return self.accel[1]

   @y.setter
   def y(self, val):
      self.accel[1] = val

   @property
   def z(self):
      return self.accel[2]

   @z.setter
   def z(self, val):
      self.accel[2] = val

   def __iadd__(self, other):
      for x in xrange(self.dimensions):
         self.accel[x] = iadd(self.accel[x], other.accel[x])
      return self

   def __add__(self, other):
      newAccel = copy.deepcopy(self)
      newAccel += other
      return newAccel

   def __str__(self):
      return "Acceleration(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.accel[0], self.accel[1], self.accel[2])

   def getVelocity(self, deltaTime):
      return Velocity(mul(self.accel[0], deltaTime), mul(self.accel[1], deltaTime), mul(self.accel[2], deltaTime))

class Velocity(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y, z):
      super(Velocity, self).__init__()
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.z = z

   def __str__(self):
      return "Velocity(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   accel = Acceleration(1.1234, 2.1234, 3.1234)
   accel += Acceleration(1, 1, 1)
   print accel

   accels = []
   for x in xrange(10):
      accel += Acceleration(1.1234, 2.1234, 3.1234)

   vel = accel.getVelocity(2)
   print "Velocity of object with acceleration %s after one second:" % (accel)
   print vel
```

prints the following:

Acceleration(2.1234, 3.1234, 4.1234)

Velocity of object with acceleration 
Acceleration(13.3574, 24.3574, 35.3574) after one second:
Velocity(26.7148, 48.7148, 70.7148)

You can get fancy for faster calculations:

```
def getFancyVelocity(self, deltaTime):
   from itertools import repeat
   x, y, z = map(mul, self.accel, repeat(deltaTime, self.dimensions))
   return Velocity(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it only provides means to add vectors and a method for approximating their integral. What I meant was a way to define the mathematical representation of the field (acceleration, in this case) but probably my question was not clear enough. I will rephrase it soon... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to store an arbitrary number of acceleration sources for a spacecraft class?

Can't you just use an array of functions?  (Function pointers when you get to c++)

i.e:

```
#pseudo Python
class Spacecraft
    terms = []
    def accelerate(t):
       a = (0,0,0)
       for func in terms:
         a+= func(t)


s = Spacecraft
s.terms.append(some_acceleration)
s.terms.append(some_other_acceleration)
ac = s.accelerate(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use instead some library which can work with vectors (in python, try numpy) and represent the acceleration as vector. Then, you are not reinventing the wheel, the + operator works like you wanted. Please correct me if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: It's not so much how to represent the force field (I would use a viable Vector package) but how to define the actual equations that model the force field.